# How to convert float to double(both stored in IEEE-754 representation) without losing precision?

Tags: c++, qt, floating-point, double, ieee-754

I mean, for example, I have the following number encoded in IEEE-754 single precision:

```
"0100 0001 1011 1110 1100 1100 1100 1100"  (approximately 23.85 in decimal)
```

The binary number above is stored in literal string.

The question is, how can I convert this string into IEEE-754 double precision representation(somewhat like the following one, but the value is not the same), WITHOUT losing precision?

```
"0100 0000 0011 0111 1101 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1001 1010"
```

which is <del>the same number</del> encoded in IEEE-754 double precision.

I have tried using the following algorithm to convert the first string back to decimal number first, but it loses precision.

```
num in decimal = (sign) * (1 + frac * 2^(-23)) * 2^(exp - 127)
```

I'm using Qt C++ Framework on Windows platform.

EDIT: I must apologize maybe I didn't get the question clearly expressed.
What I mean is that I don't know the true value 23.85, I only got the first string and I want to convert it to double precision representation without precision loss.

Comment: @tenfour I think it is because he is storing it as string

Comment: Your second binary string is _not_ the same number as the first, but in `double` precision. What is the problem you try to solve?

Comment: Daniel Fisher is correct; those are in no way the same number (the first is 23.84999847412109375, the second is 23.85000000000000142108547152020037174224853515625).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well: keep the sign bit, rewrite the exponent (minus old bias, plus new bias), and pad the mantissa with zeros on the right...

(As @Mark says, you have to treat some special cases separately, namely when the biased exponent is either zero or max.)

Comment: Thanks! The question, in fact, is that simple. I just got stuck in my mind.

Comment: You do realize that by doing that you will NOT get the result you asked for in the OP, right?

Comment: @KerrekSB: this will, in general, **not** yield the original decimal value! The versions between binary fractional number and decimal fractional numbers relies on a nice interaction between the conversion from decimal to binary and back to decimal. If you pad with zeros, the double won't convert back correctly.

Comment: @DietmarKühl: The original decimal value is not the value of the float, either. 23.85 is 477/20, which is not representable exactly as a binary float. Indeed, the nearest double to 477/20 is not the one given by my recipe. Rather, my recipe shows how to get a double of the same value as the input float.

Comment: @KerrekSB: If you do the Right Thing, you can convert a decimal fractional number into a binary floating point ("Bellerophon") and back to a decimal fraction number ("Dragon4") and you get back the original value under very reasonable restrictions (essentially, the number of decimal digits is limited by the log_2(10) rounded down). If you just pad with zeros, formatting a `double` won't yield the same value as the `float` you came from!

Comment: This works fine for finite normal nonzero numbers;  for zeros, subnormals, infinities and nans you might need to work a bit harder.  In particular, be aware that this recipe will translate +/-0.0 into something nonzero: even if you don't care about subnormals, nans and infinities, it's probably worth adding a special case for zeros.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, +1 for identifying the input in binary.

Second, that number does not represent 23.85, but slightly less.  If you flip its last binary digit from `0` to `1`, the number will still not accurately represent 23.85, but slightly more.  Those differences cannot be adequately captured in a float, but they can be approximately captured in a double.

Third, what you *think* you are losing is called accuracy, not precision.  The precision of the number always grows by conversion from single precision to double precision, while the accuracy can never improve by a conversion (your inaccurate number remains inaccurate, but the additional precision makes it more obvious).

I recommend converting to a float or rounding or adding a very small value just before displaying (or logging) the number, because visual appearance is what you *really* lost by increasing the precision.

Resist the temptation to round right after the cast and to use the rounded value in subsequent computation - this is especially risky in loops.  While this might appear to correct the issue in the debugger, the accummulated additional inaccuracies could distort the end result even more.

Answer (score 2):

IEEE-754 (and floating point in general) cannot represent periodic binary decimals with full precision. Not even when they, in fact, are rational numbers with relatively small integer numerator and denominator. Some languages provide a rational type that may do it (they are the languages that also support unbounded precision integers).

As a consequence those two numbers you posted are NOT the same number.

They in fact are:

10111.11011001100110011000000000000000000000000000000000000000 ...
10111.11011001100110011001100110011001100110011001101000000000 ...

where `...` represent an infinite sequence of `0`s.

Stephen Canon in a comment above gives you the corresponding decimal values (did not check them, but I have no reason to doubt he got them right).

Therefore the conversion you want to do cannot be done as the single precision number does not have the information you would need (you have NO WAY to know if the number is in fact periodic or simply looks like being because there happens to be a repetition).

Comment: Sorry I don't get it. It's said in C Programming there is no precision loss in converting "float" to "double", looks like a paradox here....

Comment: There is no precision loss. If you convert the float to double you get the same value. The problem is that you do NOT want to get the same value, you want to get another value. Think it in decimal, A decimal floating point with 6 digits of mantissa could store 123.4545 (as 1.234545*10^2). If you go to 8 digits you get 123.4545 (as 1.23454500*10^2) with no loss of precision. But what you would like to get is 123.454545 which is another number.

Answer (score 1):

It might be easiest to convert the string into an actual float, convert that to a double, and convert it back to a string.

Answer (score -1):

Binary floating points cannot, in general, represent decimal fraction values exactly. The conversion from a decimal fractional value to a binary floating point (see "Bellerophon" in "How to Read Floating-Point Numbers Accurately" by William D.Clinger) and from a binary floating point back to a decimal value (see "Dragon4" in "How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately" by Guy L.Steele Jr. and Jon L.White) yield the expected results because one converts a decimal number to the closest representable binary floating point and the other controls the error to know which decimal value it came from (both algorithms are improved on and made more practical in David Gay's [dtoa.c](http://www.netlib.org/fp/dtoa.c). The algorithms are the basis for restoring `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` decimal digits (except, potentially, trailing zeros) from a floating point value stored in type `T`.

Unfortunately, expanding a `float` to a `double` wrecks havoc on the value: Trying to format the new number will in many cases not yield the decimal original because the `float` padded with zeros is different from the closest `double` Bellerophon would create and, thus, Dragon4 expects. There are basically two approaches which work reasonably well, however:

1. As someone suggested convert the `float` to a string and this string into a `double`. This isn't particularly efficient but can be proven to produce the correct results (assuming a correct implementation of the not entirely trivial algorithms, of course).
2. Assuming your value is in a reasonable range, you can multiply it by a power of 10 such that the least significant decimal digit is non-zero, convert this number to an integer, this integer to a `double`, and finally divide the resulting double by the original power of 10. I don't have a proof that this yields the correct number but for the range of value I'm interested in and which I want to store accurately in a `float`, this works.

One reasonable approach to avoid this entirely issue is to use *decimal floating point* values as described for C++ in the [Decimal TR](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2009/n2849.pdf) in the first place. Unfortunately, these are not, yet, part of the standard but I have submitted a proposal to the C++ standardization committee to get this changed.

Comment: The problem is to convert a binary floating-point number to a binary floating-point number, but this answer offers irrelevant statements about representing decimal values and converting to and from decimal. Furthermore, its statement that expanding a float to a double wreaks havoc on the value is nonsense: The value does not change. (If some piece of software to convert the double to decimal then displays it differently from the float, then that is the fault of that software and has nothing to do with the original problem.)

Comment: A common fallacy which interferes with efforts to reason about floating-point numbers is a belief that a `float` represents an exact quantity of the form M*2^N, where M and N are integers in a certain range.  It is true that a `float` has an exact "nominal" value of that form, but I wouldn't say that a `float` represents that exact quantity.  The number `2000000.13f` has a nominal value of exactly 2000000.125, but that particular `float` would be used for all values from 2000000.0625 to 2000000.1875.  Because all values from...

Comment: 2000000.1200 to 2000000.1299 would be within the possible range, digits beyond the second one after the decimal point convey no useful information; the reported value is thus rounded to 2000000.13.  Although there is no `double` whose exact nominal value is 2000000.125 (matching the float), there is none that means "something between 2000000.0625 and 2000000.1875".  The `double` with the same nominal value has a different semantic meaning.